# Finding Modulus for large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I find the modulus for the following?

$$744{,}121{,}837 \bmod  101$$

The answer for this is 95. But how can I solve for this manually?

Comment: Perform division with remainder?

Comment: $37 - 18 + 12 - 44 + 7 = -6$

Comment: @DanielFischer Care to elaborate on your trick in an answer? I think that's what the OP wants since division with remainder is an obvious fast answer yet they're asking the question.

Comment: @user2566092 Just the alternating digit sum (in base $10^2$). I'm sure you know that one for $10^1+1$.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment, the trick here is based on the fact that $100\equiv -1$ (mod $101$).  So you have
$$
744121837 =37 + 100\cdot18+100^2\cdot12+100^3\cdot44+100^4\cdot7\\ \equiv 37-18+12-44+7\\=-6
$$
(mod $101$), which is equivalent to $95$.